# Trouble installing graphql-wp

Tags: php, wordpress, graphql

I want to install the [graphql-wp](https://github.com/tim-field/graphql-wp) plugin in a wordpress installation.

I have successfully installed composer according [these](Https://getcomposer.org/download/) instructions:

My wordpress site is installed on:

`/var/www/html/wordpress`

And I have redirected the entries to that folder:

```
<VirtualHost *: 80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/wordpress
        ServerName mydomain.com
        <Directory /var/www/html/wordpress>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow, deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog $ {APACHE_LOG_DIR} /error.log
        CustomLog $ {APACHE_LOG_DIR} /access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I followed the following steps:

```
cd  /var/www/html/wordpress
composer require mohiohio/graphql-wp
```

And everything seems to be installed correctly:

```
Using version ^ 0.1.3 for mohiohio / graphql-wp
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 4 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing webonyx / graphql-php (v0.6.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing mohiohio / wordpress-lib (0.1.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing ivome / graphql-relay-php (v0.1.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing mohiohio / graphql-wp (0.1.3): Loading from cache
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

And then I also modified the index.php by adding this line:

```
require (dirname (__ FILE__). '/vendor/autoload.php');
```

But when I go to my site:

*mydomain.com/graphql*

I get a 404 error.

(OOPS! THAT PAGE CAN’T BE FOUND)

Comment: have you activated the plugin?

Comment: I do not know how to activate.
Note that it is not a "visible" plugin through the menu.
(At least, I think so)